# textIsSelectable not working with Edittext

Tags: android, textview, copy-paste

I have seen many question like this here and lots of solution but nothing is working for me. below is my EditText xml

```
        <EditText
        android:id="@+id/summary_edittextview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:lines="15"
        android:maxLength="1000"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
```

I tried to do textIsSelectable=true which makes edittext disable and nothing happens, I tried using cursorVisible=true but that also does not solve my problem. Please help i want to allow user to copy text which is inside EditText

More Details:-
This EditText is under layout of fragment and I am using this style as app theme

```
  <style name="AppTheme.Dark" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

even if i remove textIsSelectable=true it doesn't work. Please help me where i am doing mistake.

Comment: An `EditText` is already selectable by default. Are you saying yours isn't, even without those attributes you've tried?

Comment: What do you want to do? You didn't mention that.

Comment: @MikeM. yes it didn't work even when i removed those attributes.. Please see i have updated my Question

Comment: @AshwinMothilal , I have mentioned what i want ... ok i will say it again...  i want to allow user to  be able to copy text which is inside EditText

Comment: Are you setting anyKeyListener to that edittext - null?

Comment: @AshwinMothilal , I am not using any listener

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of it? If you can?

Comment: Sorry guys ... i had some issue with device on which i was testing app ... i tested on other device its works fine now

Answer (score 2):

As @Ashwin Mothilal said What do you want to do?

OK fine. FYI, textIsSelectable is indicates that the content of a non-editable TextView can be selected.

(An EditText is always selectable, so textIsSelectable is not necessary for an EditText.)

If you DO add android:textIsSelectable to a EditText the text IS selectable, but the field is NOT editable, nor is the cursor visible.

Comment: Please see i added some more detail to my question.  I dont know why my text inside edittext are not selectable ... And thanks for the information

Answer (score 0):

Your code worked for me when I removed android:textIsSelectable="true".

Answer (score 0):

Its style problem, change it to following to check it works or not?

```
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```