# Text typed not showing on Lollipop in Fragment layout

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I have this layout of fragment:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="fragments.FrgLogin"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logoFragmentLogin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_erp24h"
        android:transitionName="logoTransition" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/loginLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/proxima_nova"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/bemVindo"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/proxima_nova"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/instrucaoLogin"
            android:textColor="@color/gray"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayoutTwo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="50dp"
            android:paddingRight="50dp"
            android:paddingTop="20dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/usernameEditText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/proxima_nova"
                android:hint="@string/usuario"
                android:textIsSelectable="true"
                android:textColor="@color/gray"
                android:textColorHint="@color/light_gray"
                android:theme="@style/loginFields" />


            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/etPasswordLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:hintEnabled="false"
                app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
                app:passwordToggleTint="@color/gray">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/passwordEditText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/proxima_nova"
                    android:hint="@string/senha"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:textColor="@color/gray"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/light_gray"
                    android:theme="@style/loginFields" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/loginEnterButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/blue_background"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:padding="6dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/loginEnterImageView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_right_arrow" />

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/loginEnterProgressBar"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:indeterminateTint="@color/white"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />
            </RelativeLayout>


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:fontFamily="@font/proxima_nova"
                android:text="@string/entrar"
                android:textColor="@color/primary"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic" />


        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

When a digit a text in username and password fields, the cursor accompanies the text, but nothing appear. This `fragment` is load inside a `Acitivty` on a `Frame Layout`. This bug happens only on `Android Lollipop` device, on emulator and real smartphone;

I can select text and copy, cut, paste, but continues invisible

Please help me !!

Methods used on Fragment class with setVisibility not working

[image: enter image description here]]

Comment: Did you share your  android:theme="@style/loginFields" code.

Comment: <style name="loginFields">
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/light_gray</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/light_gray</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/light_gray</item>
    </style>

Comment: add inputtype to your edittext like android:inputType="text"

Comment: Mohamed, not working :/

Comment: Remove `android:textIsSelectable="true"` from editttext. [See here for info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43092781/textisselectable-not-working-with-edittext)

Comment: not working :((